# Converting pandas series to iterable of iterables

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to use `MultiLabelBinarizer` in sklearn. I have a pandas series and I want to feed that series as input to `MultiLabelBinarizer`'s fit function. However, I see that MultiLabelBinarizer's fit needs an input of form `iterable of iterables`. I am not sure how can I convert pandas series to required type.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

data = pd.read_csv("somecsvFile")
y = pd.DataFrame(data['class'])

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
y = mlb.fit(???)
```

I tried converting it to numpy array, tried using iter function of pandas, but nothing seems to be working.

Please suggest me some way.

Thanks

Edit1:  Output of `print(data['class'].head(10))` is:

```
0        func
1        func
2        func
3    non func
4        func
5        func
6    non func
7    non func
8    non func
9        func
Name: status_group, dtype: object
```

Comment: What does your data frame look like? This solution is easy, I just need to know what columns your df has.

Comment: Can you post an output of `print(data['class'].head(10))`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Edited question to add ouput of head.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to workaround the fact that `MultiLabelBinarizer's fit needs an input of form iterable of iterables`:

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
      class
0      func
1      func
2      func
3  non func
4      func
5      func
6  non func
7  non func
8  non func
9      func

In [10]: import pandas as pd
    ...: from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

In [11]: y = df['class'].str.split(expand=False)   # <--- NOTE !!!

In [12]: mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
    ...: y = mlb.fit_transform(y)
    ...:

In [13]: y
Out[13]:
array([[1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

**UPDATE:** [as proposed by @unutbu you can use `pd.get_dummies()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45289631/converting-pandas-series-to-iterable-of-iterables/45289790?noredirect=1#comment77542509_45289790)

```
In [21]: pd.get_dummies(df['class'])
Out[21]:
   func  non func
0     1         0
1     1         0
2     1         0
3     0         1
4     1         0
5     1         0
6     0         1
7     0         1
8     0         1
9     1         0
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, yeah, that error message is not 100% clear. Thank you! :)

Comment: This seems to interpret `non func` to be 2 labels: both `non` and `func`. If the OP wants `non func` to be one label distinct from `func`, then perhaps `pd.get_dummies(df['class']).values` would suffice.

Comment: @unutbu, thank you for your comment! That's true. I just wanted to show OP how to workaround the `fit needs an input of form iterable of iterables` error. I'm also not sure that the `MultiLabelBinarizer` is the best choice in this case...

Comment: Yes. This is treating "non func" as both func and non. I want that to be classified as single label.But I got the idea. I will make it work now. Btw, Just curious on why you think MultiLabelBinarizer is not the best choice here?

Answer (score 4):

## What you asked

`MultiLabelBinarizer` takes an iterable of iterables.

`df['class']` is an iterable in that the values are one dimensional.you can make it two dimensional and solve your problem.

```
mlb.fit_transform(df[['class']].values)
# equivalently
# mlb.fit_transform(df['class'].values[:, None])

array([[1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

---

**A Closer Look**
This example has a 3 unique values and will produce 3 columns.

```
mlb.fit_transform([
    ['a'],
    ['b'],
    ['a'],
    ['c']
])

array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

However, we can pass non-uniform sub-lists as well

```
mlb.fit_transform([
    ['a'],
    ['b', 'a'],
    ['a'],
    ['c', 'b']
])

array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1]])
```

Though your case doesn't take advantage of this, this is why it takes an iterable of iterables so that it can do what I just showed.

---

## What I'd do instead

Because `MultiLabelBinarizer` can do more than we need, we may be able to do something better with a sharper tool

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df['class'].values)
np.eye(u.size, dtype=int)[f]

array([[1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

---

**Compare Timing**

```
%timeit mlb.fit_transform(df['class'].values[:, None])

10000 loops, best of 3: 191 µs per loop

%%timeit
f, u = pd.factorize(df['class'].values)
np.eye(u.size, dtype=int)[f]

10000 loops, best of 3: 68.8 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for clear description. I got the idea clearly now.